# Parse.com - How to upload a JSON file using the REST API

Tags: json, rest, upload, parse-platform

I am trying to upload a JSON file using Parse's REST API with no success so far.

The request I am trying to make is the following:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{ "name" : "myName" }' \
https://api.parse.com/1/files/test.json
```

The reponse is as follows:

```
{"code":1,"error":"internal error"}
```

I believe my request is correct, the JSON is valid, my Application ID and REST API Key are also correct.

To top it off, I can successfully upload an invalid JSON.  For example, the same request with an invalid JSON:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '#{ "name" : "myName" }' \
https://api.parse.com/1/files/test.json
```

Returns a correct reponse JSON:

```
{
    "url":"http://files.parsetfss.com/e88af32e-2e48-400b-aa1c-2f167f3d2785/tfss-550782bd-718c-46b1-bac1-9e366f957d7a-test.json",
    "name":"tfss-550782bd-718c-46b1-bac1-9e366f957d7a-test.json"
}
```

Has anyone had similar problems, or could anyone point me what I am doing wrong?

[]'s!

Comment: What happens if you try with `Content-Type: text/plain`?

Comment: I still get the same results on both cases.  Am I supposed to use a custom class if I want to upload a JSON file.

Comment: I think you should log a bug from the help page: https://parse.com/help